# Python: Getting started with tk, widget not resizing on grid?

Tags: python, tkinter, resize, tk-toolkit, grid-layout

I'm just getting started with Python's `Tkinter`/`ttk` and I'm having issues getting my widgets to resize when I use a grid layout. Here's a subset of my code which exhibits the same issue as the full code (I realize that this subset is so simple that I'd probably be better off using `pack` instead of `grid`, but I figure this will help cut through to the main problem and once I understand, I can fix it everywhere it occurs in my full program):

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # Create my widgets
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self)
        ysb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='vertical', command=self.tree.yview)
        xsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient='horizontal', command=self.tree.xview)
        self.tree.configure(yscroll=ysb.set, xscroll=xsb.set)
        self.tree.heading('#0', text='Path', anchor='w')

        # Populate the treeview (just a single root node for this simple example)
        root_node = self.tree.insert('', 'end', text='Test', open=True)

        # Lay it out on a grid so that it'll fill the width of the containing window.
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
        self.tree.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='nse')
        xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='sew')
        self.grid()
        master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

app = App(tk.Tk())
app.mainloop()
```

I want to make it so that my tree view fills the entire width of the window it's in, but instead the tree view is just centering itself in the middle of the window.

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `import Tkinter as tk` on the first line?

Comment: @Kevin - Correct. Funny thing: I manually wrote the first 3 lines of code, before thinking "I better just copy and paste to avoid making mistakes", and copying and pasting the rest in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the `sticky` argument when you do `self.grid`. Without it, the Frame won't resize when the window does. You'll also need to `rowconfigure` master and self, just as you have `columnconfigure`d them.

```
    #rest of code goes here...
    xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='sew')
    self.grid(sticky="nesw")
    master.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    master.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

---

Alternatively, instead of gridding the Frame, `pack` it and specify that it fills the space it occupies. Since the Frame is the only widget in the Tk, it doesn't really matter whether you `pack` or `grid`.

```
    #rest of code goes here...
    xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='sew')
    self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin! You were right, all I needed to change to make it start resizing with the window was add in `sticky='nsew'` as an argument to `self.grid()`. As I stated in the  question, this is just a minimal subset of my code that demonstrates the problem I was having - my actual program's layout has more to it that makes `grid()` preferable to `pack()`. But fixing that one line fixes all the scaling in my full program. Thanks again!