# resizable window frame in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I created a window with tkinter for my programm but I want it to resize itself when the user resizes the window. Right now when I increase or decrease the size of the window the widgets stay at the same position and don't in-/decrease in size.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Graphicaluserinterface(tk.Frame):


    def __init__(self,master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        self.check1 = tk.IntVar()
        self.fileopenname1 = tk.StringVar()
        self.entrystring = tk.IntVar()
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.filemenu=tk.Menu(self.menubar,tearoff=0)
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File",menu=self.filemenu)
        self.filemenu.add_command(label="Exit",command = root.destroy)
        self.helpmenu=tk.Menu(self.menubar,tearoff=0)

        self.programmstart = tk.Button(self, text = "Start Program")
        self.programmstart.grid(row=10,column=8,sticky = "W")

        self.checkbutton1 = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "Drehzahl und Drehmoment",variable=self.check1,onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
        self.checkbutton1.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky = "W")

        self.leer1 = tk.Label(self,text="                               ") #erzeugt leere Zelle, sonst ist startbutton links
        self.leer1.grid(row=0,column=3,columnspan=5)
        self.leer2 = tk.Label(self,text="                               ")
        self.leer2.grid(row=5,column=8,rowspan=2)
        self.leer3 = tk.Label(self,text="                               ")
        self.leer3.grid(row=9,column=9)

        self.inputpathdisplay = tk.Label(self,textvariable=self.fileopenname1,bg="white",width=60)
        self.inputpathdisplay.grid(row=1,column=8,columnspan=3,sticky = "W")
        self.inputpathdisplaylabel = tk.Label(self,text="Inputfile")
        self.inputpathdisplaylabel.grid(row=0,column=8,columnspan=3)


root = tk.Tk()
app = Graphicaluserinterface(master=root)
app.master.title("Programm")
app.master.minsize(800,300)
root.config(menu=app.menubar)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: I think the questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25940217/python-getting-started-with-tk-widget-not-resizing-on-grid and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644339/python-tkinter-resize-widgets-evenly-in-a-window should help.

Comment: when i use the information provided in the link, my window is now resizable but all the widgets are at a different position

Comment: I think it's because you need to change the `sticky` option when you grid the widgets. If you want a widget to resize with the window, you need to use `widget.grid(.., sticky='ewns')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the weight on your grid's rows and columns. The following is a refactored version of your code that should act a little more as you were hoping. Please continue development from this code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter
from tkinter.constants import *


class GraphicalUserInterface(tkinter.Frame):

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        root = tkinter.Tk()
        root.title('Program')
        root.minsize(560, 105)
        gui = cls(root)
        gui.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root['menu'] = gui.menubar
        cls.create_toplevel(root, 'First Toplevel')
        root.mainloop()

    @staticmethod
    def create_toplevel(root, window_title):
        window = tkinter.Toplevel(root)
        window.title(window_title)
        window.minsize(560, 105)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.check_value = tkinter.BooleanVar()
        self.filename = tkinter.StringVar()
        self.menubar = tkinter.Menu(self)
        self.file_menu = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=FALSE)
        self.help_menu = tkinter.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=FALSE)
        self.program_start = tkinter.Button(
            self, text='Start Program',
            command=lambda: self.create_toplevel(self.master, 'Another Window')
        )
        self.check_button = tkinter.Checkbutton(
            self, text='Speed ​​& Torque', variable=self.check_value,
            onvalue=True, offvalue=False
        )
        self.input_path_display = tkinter.Label(
            self, textvariable=self.filename, bg='white', width=60
        )
        self.input_path_display_label = tkinter.Label(self, text='Input File')
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label='File', menu=self.file_menu)
        self.file_menu.add_command(label='Exit', command=self.master.destroy)
        pad = dict(padx=5, pady=5)
        self.check_button.grid(row=0, column=0, **pad)
        self.input_path_display_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=EW, **pad)
        self.input_path_display.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=NSEW, **pad)
        self.program_start.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=EW, **pad)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GraphicalUserInterface.main()
```

Comment: thanks alot for this answer it´s working as i wanted it. Two questions though:
1.) from which part of the code does "input_path_display" increase vertically ?
2.) what is the reasoning in putting the widgets in the __init__ method and the grid method for those widgets into the "ccreate_widgets" method ?

Comment: also how do i implement Toplevel windows ? Before i´d define them as:
tkinter.Toplevel(root) but this doesnt work now

Comment: @James (1) Refer to lines 14, 15, 44, and 46. (2) PyCharm was complaining that new instance variables were being defined outside of `__init__`. There are at least two solutions to that problem. First, you can set them all to `None` and then reassign them later; or second, you can put all the assignments in the initializer. My recommendation to you would be to rename `create_widgets` to something more appropriate -- like `place_widgets` or `grid_widgets`.

Comment: ok thank you for all the information, i will try around and add some more checkbuttons.
By the way i am not sure if it´s my jupyter notebook or my computer, but everytime i press the exit in the menubar (you put the command self.tk.quit) my programm freezes and the kernel needs to restart.

Comment: @James For your second comment, see my edit. A `staticmethod` was added that shows how a toplevel window can be created. Where you put it in your code is up to you but should probably be organized in a way that is easy to maintain and understand.

Comment: @James `self.tk.quit` has been replaced with `self.master.destroy`. It should be noted that this may or may not do what you want. Your primary widget is a `Frame`. When your `GraphicalUserInterface` is placed within a window with multiple other widgets and someone tries to exit the program, the container for your `GraphicalUserInterface` along with any other widgets it contains will be destroyed. Your application might not even close. My goal in using `self.tk.quit` was to actually cause the application to shutdown completely. My development is carried out on Windows using PyCharm.

Comment: i am a bit embarassed since i never used @staticmethod, i don´t seem to understand how to call it

Comment: when clicking the button i mean, i tried command=self.create_toplevel(self) but now the window appears before clicking

Comment: @James See my modifications on lines 18, 22, 24, and 34-37. Everytime the button is clicked, a new toplevel window is created. On a side note, you should ask new questions separately for the sake of those that use your question to answer their own. You can provide a link to this question if you believe this question is still relevant to other questions that you have. The policy of having one question per thread on the StackExchange network is to make it easier for others to do research regarding their own problems. Having multiple question per thread makes that more difficult.

Comment: ok thank you i think i understand it now, i will create new threads if i have more questions.